# Less mixin calling another mixin won't generate nested rules

Tags: less

I have a Less project set up with three files relevant to my question.

- A config file which just holds variables and their values.
- A controller file which my Less watcher is told to compile.
- A mixin file, titled _buttons.less, which I import as a reference in the
  controller file.

Inside the controller file, I have a rule:

```
.bananas {
    .nesting-mixin(@color-list);
}
```

Inside the variable file, I have a list:

```
@color-list : red, blue, green, black;
```

Inside the mixin file, I have two mixins:

```
.do-the-mixin(@list) {
    color: extract(@list, 1);
    &.blue {
        color: extract(@list, 2);
    }
    &.green {
        color: extract(@list, 3);
    }
}
.nesting-mixin(@list) {
    &.colored {
        .do-the-mixin(@list);
    }
}
```

When I call the `.nesting-mixin` method from the controller file, the output is:

```
.bananas.colored {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

But when I move the nesting mixin into the controller file, I get:

```
.bananas.colored {
  color: #ff0000;
}
.bananas.colored {
  color: #ff0000;
}
.bananas.colored.blue {
  color: #0000ff;
}
.bananas.colored.green {
  color: #008000;
}
```

Is there some aspect of Less mixin importing or nesting that I don't understand?  The second output is what I want, but I don't understand why it needs to be in the same file from which it's called.

Thanks for reading. :)

Comment: Just do not use `reference` with mixin files (Actually I'd say *never* use `reference` unless absolutely unavoidable. Since your mixins are parametric there's no reason to not import a file containing them the normal way).

Comment: Hah... wow that solved the problem!  Add it as an answer ;)

Comment: I guess a good an answer needs to be a bit more reasonable (on why the recommendation is so harsh ("never!" :)) And that's a long story...

Comment: Well thanks either way.